# Lockfree Reloading and Sharing of const objects

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, lock-free

My application's configuration is a const object that is shared with multiple threads. The configuration is stored in a centralized location and any thread may reach it. I've tried building a lockfree implementation that would allow me to load new configuration while still allowing other threads to read the last known configuration.

My current implementation has a race between updating the `shared_ptr` and reading from it.

```
template<typename T>
class ConfigurationHolder
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<T> SPtr;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<const T> CSPtr;

    ConfigurationHolder() : m_active(new T()) {}

    CSPtr get() const { return m_active; } // RACE - read

    template<typename Reloader>
    bool reload(Reloader reloader)
    {
        SPtr tmp(new T());
        if (!tmp)
            return false;
        if (!reloader(tmp))
            return false;
        m_active=tmp; // RACE - write
        return true;
    }

private:
    CSPtr m_active;
};
```

I can add a `shared_mutex` for the problematic read/write access to the `shared_ptr`, but I'm looking for a solution that will keep the implementation lockfree.

EDIT: My version of GCC does not support `atomic_exchange` on `shared_ptr`

EDIT2: Requirements Clarification: I have multiple readers and may have multiple reloaders (although this is less common). Readers need to hold a configuration object and that it would not change while they are reading it. Old configuration objects must be freed when the last reader is done with them.

Comment: Can you elaborate the use case? If you have many readers, and one thread decides to reload then 1) You need a semaphore, not mutex and 2) When should the other threads start reading the new value? It's not clearly defined until when they should read the old one.

Comment: @kabanus Edited with clarifications. Plus, I would like to avoid adding mutexes/semaphores, if possible.

Comment: You're describing a read write semaphore exactly. Reading operations are free, and writing can only be done when semaphore is clear. Anything you implement with counters would be just that. Assuming the pointer assignment is not atomic, (it could be with  std::atomic<T*>), you would have to make a r/w semaphore. I can show you one of these, otherwise I don't have a solution.

Comment: I wanted to use boost's `shared_mutex`, but read access is not free. There's always a lock to test the writer state. But in any case, I'm looking for a lockfree solution if possible.

Comment: Last comment, to avoid a discussion - it is possible to write a semaphore class/shared mutex class that does not block read, but does block write. EDIT: boost shared_mutex is exactly this : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.shared_mutex

Comment: Do your gcc have atomic_store?

Comment: For a read-mostly data structure, you probably want something that allows the readers to be lock-free, like a RCU (read-copy-update).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-copy-update.  Writers make a copy and modify that, then change a pointer atomically.  (Then at some point after being sure all readers have finished with the old version, it can be freed.  This is one of the ways this gets tricky.)

Comment: @UKMonkey. Nope. :(

Comment: @PeterCordes I actually don't need to update according to existing data. I reload the configuration from some external source and place it instead of the old configuration.

Comment: @Shloim: that makes the "copy and update" part of RCU a lot simpler then, but the synchronization pattern is identical.  And the challenge of finding points where any possible readers are done with the old copy so you can free it still exists.

Comment: That is my question here. How would I go about and implement it? The `shared_ptr` has proven problematic for this case.

Comment: Do reloaders have to operate on fresh data, or are they creating a from scratch version?

Comment: Creating from scratch (reading from disk)

Comment: Are you ok with there being a writer lock, if reading is lock free? (to prevent two writers from writing at the same time).

Comment: @NirFriedman Yes.

Comment: @Shloim I thought I had an answer, but there was a subtle race condition in it. If you have access to a lock free queue, I think you can reuse this to accomplish your goal. Writers push back into the queue, and after that they enter into a loop where they try to pop off the queue, until the queue is only size 1. Readers peek at the front element of the queue.

Comment: I also thought of this using `boost::lockfree:queue`, but the verification of `queue.size()==1` is also a race condition, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You should just update your compiler to get atomic shared pointer ops.

Failing that, wrap it in a `shared_timed_mutex`.  Then test how much it costs you.

Both of these are going to be less work than correctly writing your own lock-free shared pointer system.

If you have to:

---

This is a hack, but it might work.  It is a read-copy-update style on the pointer itself.

Have a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::shared_ptr<T>>>`.  Have a `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T> const*>` "current" pointer, and a `std::atomic<std::size_t> active_readers`.

The `vector` stores your still living `shared_ptr`s.  When you want to change, push a new one on the back.  Keep a copy of this `shared_ptr`.

Now swap the "current" pointer for the new one.  Busy-wait until `active_readers` hits zero, or until you get bored.

If `active_readers` hit zero, filter your `vector` for `shared_ptr`s with a use-count of 1.  Remove them from the `vector`.

Regardless, now drop the extra `shared_ptr` you ketp to the state you created.  And done writing.

If you need more than one writer, lock this process using a separate mutex.

On the reader side, increment `active_readers`.  Now atomically load the "current" pointer, make a local copy of the pointed-to `shared_ptr`, then decrement `active_readers`.

However, I just wrote this.  So it probably contains bugs.  Proving concurrent design correct is *hard*.

By far the easiest way to make this reliable is to upgrade your compiler and get atomic operations on a shared_ptr.

---

This is probably overly complex and I think we can set it up so that the `T` are cleaned up when the last reader goes away, but I aimed for correctness rather than efficiency on recycling `T`.

---

With minimial sync on the readers, you could use a condition variable to signal that a reader is done with a given `T`; but that involves a tiny bit of contention with the writer thread.

---

Practically, lock-free algorithms are often slower than lock based, because the overhead of a mutex isn't as high as you fear.

A `shared_timed_mutex` wrapping a `shared_ptr`, where the writer is simply overwriting the variable, is going to be pretty darn fast.  Existing readers are going to keep their old `shared_ptr` just fine.